# ClickOnce publish error. Failed to copy dll.deploy files

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, clickonce

I just finished a WPF project in C# , it worked great until couple of minutes ago. Then I deleted some files that I don't need anymore ,like Page1.xaml and Page1.xaml.cs .
Then I tried to publish the project with ClickOnce, and I got 129 errors...

"
Error       Failed to copy file 'C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\OATradex\bin\Release\app.publish\Application Files\OATrade_1_0_0_15\System.Xml.XPath.dll.deploy' to 'C:/Users/xxxxxx/Downloads/OANDA/release/Application Files/OATrade_1_0_0_15/System.Xml.XPath.dll.deploy'. 
Unable to add 'Application Files/OATrade_1_0_0_15/System.Xml.XPath.dll.deploy' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Application Files\OATrade_1_0_0_15\System.Xml.XPath.dll.deploy'.  The system cannot find the path specified.   OATrade     1
"

Can anybody help me please. I am completely lost, I do not know what to do!!!
I tried to check uncheck "Just My Code" deleted bin folder nothing helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Running Visual Studio as administrator solved the problem.

Comment: Running as administrator once, or for evermore?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a problem in the **permission** settings of destination path.